# I'm using prettyphoto light box in XHTML, but it is not working. Kindly give me a solution

Tags: xhtml

How to include the script in XHTML? If I'm using this code in HTML it is working. But it is not working in XHTML.

```xhtml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>jQuery lightbox clone - prettyPhoto - by Stephane Caron</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!--script src="js/jquery.lint.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <h1>GALLERIES</h1>

            <ul class="gallery clearfix">
                <li><a href="images/fullscreen/1.JPG?lol=lol" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="You can add caption to pictures. You can add caption to pictures. You can add caption to pictures."><img src="images/thumbnails/t_1.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Red round shape" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/fullscreen/2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Nice building" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/fullscreen/3.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_3.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Fire!" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/fullscreen/4.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_4.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Rock climbing" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/fullscreen/5.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_5.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Fly kite, fly!" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="images/fullscreen/6.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Nice building" /></a></li>
            </ul>

            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("area[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();

                $(".gallery:first a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'light_square',slideshow:3000, autoplay_slideshow: true});
                $(".gallery:gt(0) a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'fast',slideshow:10000, hideflash: true});

                $("#custom_content a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:first").prettyPhoto({
                    custom_markup: '<div id="map_canvas" style="width:260px; height:265px"></div>',
                    changepicturecallback: function(){ initialize(); }
                });

                $("#custom_content a[rel^='prettyPhoto']:last").prettyPhoto({
                    custom_markup: '<div id="bsap_1259344" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6"></div><div id="bsap_1237859" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6" style="height:260px"></div><div id="bsap_1251710" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271ccbf01a33f2b6d6"></div>',
                    changepicturecallback: function(){ _bsap.exec(); }
                });
            });
            </script>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scripts in XHTML can't contain `<` signs. There are differences between HTML and XHTML. In XHTML, scripts don't have a CDATA content type: the contents is treated exactly the same as any other element.

So, possible solutions are:

- Put the script in a separate file, so that its contents will not be mangled by the XML parser.
- Replace all `<` signs with the entity reference `&lt;`.
- If the script doesn't contain `]]>`, you can put the whole content in a `<![CDATA[` .. `]]>` block.
- Change the file type of the XHTML document to HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But my client wants XHTML document. If any possible didn't chage that file type?

Comment: Then you have 3 solutions left; take your pick.